# Custom text drawing using DrawIndexedPrimitives, some letters not showing up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I've found that there are too many issues with `SpriteFont`, for me to be able to deal with, so I've elected to write my own font class and draw strings using `GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives` using a `DynamicVertexBuffer` and `DynamicIndexBuffer` (for strings that change).

I hadn't noticed any problems in the simulator, but when running on a device, when displaying a large amount of text in a single call to `DrawIndexedPrimitives`, many contiguous letters will some times not show up.  It doesn't change on a frame-by-frame basis, so it seems like the data in the vertex buffer or index buffer is just wrong or something.

Is there any explanation as to why some contiguous set of primitives in the middle of a larger set (never at the beginning or the end) will just not show up?  And keep in mind that it all worked fine on the simulator.  It's not a culling problem, I tried turning that off, and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem only when the application was running on an older prototype device.  Real devices seem to be working fine.